# Microsoft Power Automate and Azure Devops with guest users

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate

In our ADO organization, all the users are registered in AD as guest users.
My user is set as the organization owner.

I'm trying to create a flow in Power Automate, but this organization does not appear in the list of organizations.
I tried to type its name manually as a custom value. This work for configuring the trigger, and also a step of "Get Work Item Details". but when configuring a step of "Update Work Item Details" I get an authentication error:

> The dynamic operation request to API 'visualstudioteamservices'
> operation 'GetWorkItemSchemaForUpdate' failed with status code
> 'Unauthorized'. This may indicate invalid input parameters